# Cannot open Excel files from Linux if on Nas Server

Tags: libreoffice, nas

I connected to my QNAP NAS Server in Linux in the filemange with smb (smb://192.168.6.101/).

I logged in with a User who has read and write rights. On the Server i can edit text files etc.

However if i try to open a excel file with libre office or wps office (I tryed both to make sure its not a bug in the office)  i always get a error like no permission.

So what can i do? Do i have to change the rights somewhow? Im quite confused on windows i can connect to the same Server and directly edit the excel file on it.

Comment: Does it work when you mount the samba share?

Comment: I added the share in fstab and there it works.

Comment: Desktop Environment? (Gnome, KDE, XFCE...)